# Making an eventlistener of Picker

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium-mobile

Hi I am making an eventListener for picker. Here is my code:

```
var YahooScreen = require("YahooScreen");
var ESPNScreen = require("ESPNScreen");
var CBSScreen = require("CBSScreen");
var ApiWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var ApiLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
   text  : 'I am Fantasy Expert at',
   top   : '28%',
   left  : '10%',
   right : '10%',
   height: 'auto',
   width : 'auto',
   color : '#000',
   font  : { fontSize : 28,fontWeight : 'bold'},
   textAlign : 'center'
});

ApiWin.add(ApiLabel);

var ApiPicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
   Top : '35%',
   left : '25%',
   width : '50%'
});

ApiPicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   if (e.row == 'Yahoo!') {
      alert('I am in Yahoo')
   } else if (e.row == 'ESPN') {
      alert('I am in ESPN');
   } else {
      alert('I am in CBS')
   }
});

var data = [];
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
   title : 'Yahoo!'
}));

data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : 'Espn!'
}));
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
   title : 'CBS Sports!'
}));

ApiPicker.add(data);
ApiWin.add(ApiPicker);
ApiWin.open();
```

When Yahoo is selected Yahoo alert should be shown and likewise but it only showing I am in CBS alert could you solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you try setting a breakpoint or logging `e` to console to see why?

Comment: What platform you're using? Android or ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wahab, This is really simple. If you want to get the selected row title try it, I got the title by using the following code

```
//Here you will get the title of selected row title
ApiPicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   alert('Selected row = ' + ApiPicker.getSelectedRow(0).title);
   //e.row.title will also give the same effect but above one is the best way
});
```

Read [getSelectedRow function](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-getSelectedRow)

This one also will work

```
ApiPicker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      //alert(e.row.title);
      if('Yahoo!' === e.row.title){
        alert('yahoo');
      } else if('Espn!' === e.row.title){
        alert('espn');
      } else{
        alert('cbs sports');
      }
});
```

Also you can insert the data into the picker as follows

```
//Your data list
var listData = ["Yahoo!","Espn!","CBS Sports"];
var data = [];
for( var index = 0,len = listData.length; index < len; index++ )
{
    data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
        title : listData[index]
    }));
}

ApiPicker.add(data);
```

This will be much more easier than your method. If you follow this method, you can create more rows by adding the title to the arrays. Otherwise your code size will be large. This will be simple and easier one.